# How to determine the only additional file in otherwise two identical listings?

Tags: command-line, files, diff

I have done a listing of the device folder two times, one time without the sd-card in the slot and one time inserted, the system automatically adds one 
file in the device folder.

```
$ ls /dev | wc -l
205
$ ls /dev | wc -l
206
```

I could put each listing into a separate file:  `ls /dev > foo`.
But how can I determine from this point the device file that was added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run this before adding the device to store the inital list
in a file:

```
ls /dev >~/a
```

And then this after adding the device:

```
ls /dev | diff -u ~/a -
```

This should show you in what way the two lists of files differ. `diff`
shows the differences between two text files, and flag `-u` changes its
output format: lines added will be prefixed with a `+` sign. For
example, if you get the following output (I omitted the diff header):

```
 sdc
 sdd
 sde
+sdf
 sg0
 sg1
 sg2
```

then it means that the new device that got created is `/dev/sdf`.

You can then delete the temporary file `~/a`.

Another way to get the information you are looking for would be to `tail -f /var/log/messages`: you should see kernel messages mentioning the new device's appearance and disappearance.

Comment: a is here just another name for the file like foo, right ?

Comment: Yes, you can call the file anything you like, as long as you use the same name in both commands.

Comment: I do not understand this diff command and the -u option at all, but I opened a new question about it.

Comment: I will edit my answer to explain this use of diff.